# Multiple ViewModels in View WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, binding

How to,bind the property of first/second/third Viewmodel to a grid column in a single view.

How could I explicitly reference each property in the appropriate view model to grid column in view..!

```
DataContext="{DynamicResource VMContainer}">
<Window.Resources>
    <vm:VMContainer x:Key="VMContainer"/>
</Window.Resources>

public class VMContainer
{
    public FirstViewModel   VM1 { get; set; }
    public SecondViewModel  VM2 { get; set; }
    public ThirdViewModel  VM3 { get; set; }
}
```

If it is a single viewmodel, can do like below.

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource VMContainer}}

GridColumn Header="Salary" Binding="{Binding Salary, Mode=TwoWay}"
```

Tried like below:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource VMContainer}}">
   <ListView.View>
     <GridView x:Name="grdTest">
               <GridViewColumn Header="Salary" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding VM1.Salary / VMContainer.M1.Salry, Mode=TwoWay}" Width="100" />           
     </GridView>
</ListView.View>

InitializeComponent();
VMContainer VMC = new VMContainer();
DataContext = VMC;
```

How could I explicitly reference each property in the appropriate view model to grid column in view..! 
View model composed of other view models(Composite ViewModel in wpf_mvvm)

Issue is, always VMC returns null, I would appreciate for any suggestion..!

Comment: Am confused. What's the difference between ViewModelCombine and VMContainer. What is ViewModelCombine?

Comment: And what does "..Not working" mean?  Any errors in the Output window?

Comment: Thanks Henk Holterman...
Not working means..Not binding the data...!

Comment: I see and you are doing it wrong. ItemsSource must be databound to a List, Array or another collection. What exactly do you want to achieve? What should be the rows in your GridView and what should be the columns? In my example, rows are employess and column is salary of the employees

Comment: I want to display all 10 columns in one grid from my three different viewmodels and each viewmodel having one collection like collection1,collection2 & Collection3.

Answer (score 0):

if you had something like this:

```
public class FirstViewModel
{
    public double Salary {get; set;}
}
```

then this would work:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding VM1.Salary}" />
```

However, when you are using ItemsControl like DataGrid, or GridView, the bindings defined in GridColumns must refer to items defined in ItemsSouce. For example:

```
public class Employee
{
    public double Salary {get; set;}
}

public class FirstViewModel
{
    public FirstViewModel()
    {
          Employees = new List<Employee>
          {
              new Employee() { Salary=10000 }
              new Employee() { Salary=15000 }
          }
    }
    public List<Employee> Employees {get;}
}
```

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{VM1.Employees}">
   <DataGrid.Columns>
       <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Salary}" />
```